# Get primary keys after inserting data into SQL Server database using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, primary-key, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` to insert records into a SQL Server database. I have a requirement to save the data into 3 tables based on the primary key which I get after inserting into 1st table. As the dataset inserts at a time without looping, I have no idea to get the primary key of the each inserted record.

Is there any possibility to get the primary keys of the rows inserted to use for the further insertions into different tables?

I'm converting the JSON input to DataSet and inserting that dataTable into SQL Server table by mapping the columns using `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: The data you are inserting should already have something that identifies the row - whether that is a single column or multiple columns.  Assuming you get back this 'primary key' from the first table - how are you relating that to the row(s) in the second and third tables?

Comment: You can't get data back from a Bulk Copy transfer. It might be easier to just pass in the JSON and parse it out using `OPENJSON` etc. Please show tables and sample JSON

Comment: Is there any other efficient way to Bulk insert data into Sql table rather than using SqlBulkCopy as getting primary key becomes a complex problem with that?

Comment: Either use a Table Valued Parameter or `INSERT... FROM OPENROWSET(BULK`. Why do you think it's so difficult to get back a primary key when using `OPENJSON`?

Comment: @Charlieface  Here is my sample Json:
[{
    "FirstName": "David",
    "LastName": "Szymanski",
    "RecipientSsn": "662-62-6311",
    "IsForeignAddress": "No",
    "Address1": "362 Main St",
},]

I'm converting this to DataTable and inserting it using BulkCopy. And for primary key I have an Identity column in my Database.